# PHP api dosen't work properly after inserting new data

Tags: php, angular, api

I have created a php api to do crud operations in my angular project. api works fine in dvelopment environment (localhost - xampp server). but after host it in bluehost webserver api dosen't work properly.

I have tried page reload open. but i also dosen't work. api works only after ctrl+f5 refresh.

This is my angular front end code -> style.insert.component.ts

```
//Method For View Style Data
  viewStyleDetails() {
    this._db.viewStyleData().subscribe((result: any) => {
      this.anyArray = [];
      this.styleDataList = [];
      this.anyArray = result;
      console.log(this.anyArray);
      this.anyArray.forEach(element => {
        this.styleDataList.push(element as StyleDetails);
      });
    });
  }
```

database service code -> database.service.ts

```
viewStyleData() {
    return this._http.get(this.commonUrl + "viewAllStyleDetails.php").pipe(map(res => res));
  }
```

view all php api code -> viewAllStyleDetails.php

```
<?php
    include "Crud.php";
    $crud= new Crud();
    $query="SELECT * FROM style_details";
    $data=$crud->getData($query);
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I want to run php api code without any refresh of the webpage. php api has to return all available data in database without refresh php api file.

Comment: can you provide the error shown in browser console ?

Comment: No error showing in the console

Comment: can you tell us how you call this function "viewStyleDetails"? by clicking a button or you call this function from ngOnInit

Comment: I use both way. In ngOnInit I call the viewStyleDetails method and get data to a array. And I bind that array to html table. So table show all the data. After saving new style data I call viewStyleDetails method again in the insertStyleDetails Button click event. So table will update according to the new data came from the api. But in the production level server this want happen. Its shows old data list. The api return same old data. But after ctrl+f5 refresh the webpage api will provide data list with new data.

Comment: I think php api doesn't work on normal web server (with c panel). So we have to create server like digital ocean droplet and install apache2 on it and run the api on it.